# Is it possible to restrict USB webcam resolution and fps system-wide on linux?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, camera, jitsi-meet

I have a Raspbian buster running on Raspberry Pi 3 model B with SVEN USB2.0 web camera.

My goal is to make a simple [meet.jit.si](https://meet.jit.si) client for my grandparents.
The problem is: when Chromium opens the web page, it always sets camera video size to some big value causing 100% CPU load and huge lags in video and audio.
To prove that the system can work fine, I tried WebRTC demo from [here](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/tree/gh-pages/src/content/peerconnection/pc1) with following config for `getUserMedia`:

```
config = { audio: true, video: { width: {max: 320},
            height: {max: 320}, frameRate: {min: 5, max: 15} } };
```

and everything worked smoothly.

The question is: is it possible to configure USB webcam driver so that
resolution never exceeds 320px and 15fps when used by Chromium?